What is the difference between OBJECT of a preposition and COMPLEMENT of a preposition in English grammar
I am an English-as-a-second-language student, and I have this doubt when studying syntactic analysis.
What is the difference between complement of a preposition and object of a preposition? Or are those just 2 different names that refer to the same thing?

Looking at answers at What are the things after prepositions called, formally? and What is a prepositional complement? would lead you to assume 'they are just 2 different names that refer to the same thing'. But people in various schools (eg the CGEL camp) wouldn't accept one term or the other.
